# How to download table data as excel sheet in yii 1 framework

Tags: php, excel, yii

I'm using Yii 1 framework. I tried to download table details as .csv file and retrieve data from table using ID.

When click the button it retrieve data and display in Network section of inspect elements. there are no errors and only the problem is do not download the file.

This is the code of controller's method.

```
public function actionDownload()
{


    $id = $_REQUEST['id'];


    $vote_record = Vote::model()->findByAttributes(array('id' => $id));


    $name = $vote_record['name'];

    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header("Content-type: application/csv");
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'. str_replace(" ", "_", strtolower($name)) . '_results.csv"');
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Pragma: public');
    ob_clean();
    flush();



    $titile = "Option, Vote Count\n";
    echo $titile;
    if (count($vote_record) > 0) {

        echo $vote_record['name'] . "," . $vote_record['total'] . "\n";

        echo "\n\n";
        echo $vote_record['opname1'] . "," . $vote_record['voteCount1'] . "\n";
        echo $vote_record['opname2'] . "," . $vote_record['voteCount2'] . "\n";
        echo $vote_record['opname3'] . "," . $vote_record['voteCount3'] . "\n";
        echo $vote_record['opname4'] . "," . $vote_record['voteCount4'] . "\n";

    }
}
```

So please help to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this solution for your problem :

```
<?php 
public function actionDownload() {
    $id = $_REQUEST['id'];
    $vote_record = Vote::model()->findByAttributes(array('id' => $id));
    $name = $vote_record['name'];

    header("Content-type: application/csv");
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'. str_replace(" ", "_", strtolower($name)) . '_results.csv"');
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
    header("Expires: 0");

    $handle = fopen('php://output', 'w');
    if (count($vote_record) > 0) {
        fputcsv($handle, array('Option', 'Vote Count'));
        fputcsv($handle, array($vote_record['name'], $vote_record['total']));
        fputcsv($handle, array($vote_record['opname1'], $vote_record['voteCount1']));
        fputcsv($handle, array($vote_record['opname2'], $vote_record['voteCount2']));
        fputcsv($handle, array($vote_record['opname3'], $vote_record['voteCount3']));
        fputcsv($handle, array($vote_record['opname4'], $vote_record['voteCount4']));
        fclose($handle);
        exit;
    }
    ob_clean();
    flush();
}
?>
```

I hope it will Helps.